# Jquery Hide Div (need an alternative)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

My website has a feature where users can select audio from a drop down box, when they do so `$.post` function is called, it outputs a div with the audio player (auto starts). The problem I have is that I do not want users seeing that audio player, when I use `.hide();` the audio player does not work in firefox, but works in other browsers. If I set the audio player width to 0px, it will not work in safari. I tried formatting the div via css

`#sound {
width:0px;
height:0px;
}` but it does not take any affect (yes, the name is correct). So is there any alternative to hide the div with it working on all browsers. Btw, the audio player is flash swf file.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Have you tried other CSS e.g. `display: none;` ?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion I made? Put the div inside a wrapper and work with the wrapper.

Comment: I did put it inside a wrapper - it works on all browsers except safari, I guess if it is not showing up on the screen, it just wont play on safari :(

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#sound').css({position: 'absolute', width: '1px', height: '1px', left: '-999px', top: '-999px'});
```

or

```
$('#sound').css('opacity', 0);
```

both are hacks, though

**addition after some of the comments** (not sure if works for him or not yet):

```
$('#sound').css({position: 'absolute', width: '1px', height: '1px', overflow: 'hidden'}).find('embed, object').css('margin-left', '1px');
```

Comment: I tried the above hacks, they work in all browsers except Safari. I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Are you saying neither works only in Safari? Does it work in Safari if you just put the player in a 1px by 1px visible div anywhere on the page?

Comment: if the DIV is visible, for ex if it is 1px, it works fine. If I change the opacity to 0, it does not work, nor does the position hack work. I am using http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/.

Comment: Interesting. One other hack that you could try is $('#sound').css({position: 'absolute', width: '1px', height: '1px', overflow: 'hidden'}).find('embed, object').css('margin-left', '1px'); which will keep your player div as as 1px visible div, but its content should be offset and hidden and appear as invisible.

Comment: Nope it does not work on safari, well I just changed it to 1 px and changed the audio player color to white, now no one can see it. Thanks a lot for your help @everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Did you not try using the CSS properties of `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`. You can even set these properties on browser detection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#sound').css('visibility', 'hidden').hide();
```

Comment: thanks, works on all browsers except safari browser for windows. :(

Comment: Sometimes, when a div is misbehaving, it's a good idea to put that div inside a wrapper div and set the position/display properties on the wrapper. If you really want to, you could even put it in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try `opacity:0;` or `visibility:hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the flash movie most browsers are smart enough to understand that it doesn't need to initialize it.

So, you could give it a very small width and height, set wmode parameter to transparent or opaque when embedding it (which allows you to place HTML elements on top of it) and then place a white div on top of the flash movie. Placing html elements on top of a flash to cover it will not count as hidden, no browser it *that* smart. *Yet* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is #sound the audio player itself, or a wrapper of it? I believe if you hide a wrapping div, it could work.